# Issue while deserializing JSON into C# Model

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-core-webapi, json-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize below json into C# but not getting any way out to achieve the same.
Please consider that number of "Box" nodes are not fixed. However, Scalability and HighData nodes are single.

I tried using Dictionary but Scalability and HighData nodes have different model

```
{ 
   "Cluster":{ 
      "Box1":{ 
         "Instance":"2",
         "CPU":"2"
      },
      "Box2":{ 
         "Instance":"1",
         "CPU":"2"
      },
      ....
      "BoxN":{ 
         "Instance":"N",
         "CPU":"2"
      },
      "Scalability":{ 
         "Type":"Hardware",
         "Kneepoint":176708
      },
      "HighData":{ 
         "DataRequired":1,
         "DataOptional":2
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You have dynamic box nodes.Did all of them belong to one Box class?If so,I suggest that the json should be modified like:"Box":["Box1":{ "Instance":"2","CPU":"2"},"Box2":{ "Instance":"1","CPU":"2"}].

Comment: track down the creator of the JSON and sentence them to a course on [JSON arrays](https://restfulapi.net/json-array/) for their crimes against schema design.

Answer (score 0):

Use Newtonsoft Json and dynamic, for example:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json)
```

or by using ExpandoObject Class
[ExpandoObject Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)